# Grouping lookup select option

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, modern-experience, grouping

I am new to SharePoint. So I would like to ask if it is possible to "group" these drop-down selections together?

My lookup table has a "user" and timestamp columns. So, whenever I add a new entry in the referenced list, it show multiple drop-down selections.

Instead of having multiple "user" in the drop-down, I would like different approach to group them up.

[image: pic]

Comment: No, it is not possible to group the lookup column selections in drop-down. you may need to change your architecture for this. Maybe creating another master list which will store the user information and then you can use lookup from this list into "timestamp" list as well as other lists.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your requirement cannot be fulfilled.

Sharepoint does not have the ability to group in drop-down selection.

Actually your requirement is similar to displaying unique values ​​in look up dropdown selections.

Maybe you can refer to this similar situation：

[How to show unique values in a lookup column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245047/how-to-show-unique-values-in-a-lookup-column)